# Can we download .js files and images P2P?

Tags: javascript, browser, p2p

I noticed that there is a p2p api in Chrome which is still under development, it make me wondering that would it be faster if I can download public data(like .js files, images) from a  nearby peer who is visiting the site too? Is there some works doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I doubt, with all the overhead involved in using a P2P protocol, that there would be a speed improvement using a P2P network to download assets.  In fact, unless those assets were fairly large (say, greater than 20Mb), most of the time your server's connection will beat out anything that isn't LAN, simply because it has a faster upload speed than most home connections.

If you want to distribute assets in a way that has real measurable performance, a [Content Delivery Network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network), such as Akamai or the new [Google Page Speed Service](http://code.google.com/speed/) tools will have a more immediate impact.  Plus, these work across the board, mobile devices and all, today.